# Correct course of action regarding interview response time

Tags: interviewing, job-search, follow-up

I had my final Amazon internship interview a bit more than 3 weeks ago. After this interview, the interviewer told me that I should contact my recruiter if I hear no response within 5 business days.

After a week, I contacted my recruiter and they told me that I would receive results 'soon'. It's been more than 2 weeks since this response and I was wondering what my correct course of action should be?

If I send a follow up email again, could it potentially hurt my chances? If I don't, do I risk somehow slipping through the cracks? Should I even follow up at all? If I have already contacted once, is it ok to contact again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule of thumb I follow for contacting a potential employer is three over three. I will follow up once a week for three weeks, then write the company off as not interested.

While it can hurt your chances to constantly ask for status updates concerning your application, a rate of one contact a week (tempered with information in the responses) can by no means be considered annoying or bothersome. This obviously does not apply if specific times are mentioned ("contact me tomorrow" or "they will make a decision in 2 weeks" are examples where it's OK and expected to contact them earlier/ later).

It's important to remember that people are human, so it's likely if they haven't contacted you back either they haven't been authorized to, or they've just been busy with other aspects of their job. A friendly email touching base on a once weekly basis can gently put them back on track without upsetting them.

Answer (score 4):

As a former Amazon employee who did interview training, their rule (the rule they teach anyway) is 48 hours for a response.  If it's already been a week with no response, then sorry to say you're probably out of luck.

That said, and I'm saying this only because I know that Amazon, as a tech giant, is looked upon as "a great place to work", etc, speaking as a **former** Amazon employee, there are plenty of reasons you should not be too upset about the outcome.  There are far better companies to work for than Amazon.